# Cannot connect to my PostgreSQL database on a GCE virtual machine

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a PostgreSQL (9.6) database that is deployed on a VM with Google Compute Engine. Unfortunately, I can figure how to access it from my local machine. I changed the configuration files for PostgreSQL as following:

In `/etc/postgresql/9.6/main/postgresql.conf` I added the following line:

```
listen_addresses = '*'                  # what IP address(es) to listen on;
```

In `/etc/postgresql/9.6/main/pg_hba.conf` I have:

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

I also added ingress and egress firewall rules on GCP as following (sorry for the bad artwork):
[image]

Finally, I enabled IP forwarding on my virtual machine.

The logs from PostgreSQL look fine:

```
2019-10-04 09:57:20.244 UTC [10015] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2019-10-04 09:57:20.244 UTC [10015] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2019-10-04 09:57:20.244 UTC [10020] LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
2019-10-04 09:57:20.247 UTC [10017] LOG:  shutting down
2019-10-04 09:57:20.279 UTC [10015] LOG:  database system is shut down
2019-10-04 09:57:21.346 UTC [10331] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2019-10-04 09:57:20 UTC
2019-10-04 09:57:21.350 UTC [10331] LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
2019-10-04 09:57:21.354 UTC [10335] LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
2019-10-04 09:57:21.354 UTC [10330] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2019-10-04 09:57:21.814 UTC [10337] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
```

But when I try to connect to it from my local machine I get a timeout:

```
silveris:~$ psql -U admin -h xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -p 5432 -d ipp
psql: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
    Is the server running on host "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

But when I connect to my VM through SSH everything works fine:

```
root@ipf-bdd-test:~# psql -U admin -h localhost -p 5432 -d ipp
Password for user admin: 
psql (9.6.15)
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.2, cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.

ipp=#
```

Can you please point me to what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your firewall rule, you only authorizes the compute default service account on this rule. By the way, with you try from your computer, you don't use the good service account and you are rejected.

When you try from another VM, the compute default service account is used and you are allowed by the firewall.

Select "apply to all" as target, and it should work.

*Do this only for development. Securing more the access is better (restrict the IP, ask a service account,...)*